# GitHub wiki select branch displayed on GitHub

Tags: github, wiki

Is it possible to configure what branch in the GitHub wiki is shown by default on GitHub. For example if I clone a GitHub wiki locally and then create, commit and push a new branch back up to GitHub, is it possible to configure GitHub to show that new branch by default?

From my testing it seems like GitHub just displays whatever is in master by default.

Comment: I could be very usefull if you intend to maintain different wikis for different branches of your project which have uncompatible interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not.**
Quoting from [Github help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/#cloning-wikis-locally-to-your-computer):

> You and your collaborators can create branches when working on wikis, but **only changes pushed to the master branch will be made live** and available to your readers.

Comment: wow... this is totally stupid, since github has 'Releases' as a first-class concept.

Comment: 2024 and it hasn't been changed :(